# Rotation around the vector $(1,2,3)^T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, linear-transformations

Find the matrix of the rotation in $\Bbb R^3$ through the angle $\alpha$ around the vector $(1, 2, 3)^T$ . We assume that the rotation is counterclockwise if we sit at the tip of the vector and looking at the origin.

Let $P(\vec x)$ be the linear transformation that rotates the coordinate system such that $z$ axis is in the direction of $(1, 2, 3)^T$, then by using some trignometry,

$P((0,0, 1)^T) = \dfrac1{\sqrt{13}}(1,2,3)^T$, $P((0,1, 0)^T) =(0,\sec \theta,\tan \theta)^T$ and $P((1,0,0)^T) =(\sec \theta,0,\tan \theta)^T$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $(1,2,3)^T$ and $(0,0,1)^T$.

Solving for $\theta$ and using matrix representation of $P$,

$$P(\vec x) = \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\sqrt{13}}{3} & 0 &\dfrac1{\sqrt{13}} \\  0&  \dfrac{\sqrt{13}}{3}& \dfrac2{\sqrt{13}} \\\dfrac{-2}{3} &  \dfrac{-2}{3}&  \dfrac3{\sqrt{13}}  \end{bmatrix}\vec x$$

Therefore, I got the final rotation transformation as $T(\vec x) := (P^{-1}\circ R_\alpha \circ P)(\vec x)$, where $$R_\alpha(\vec x) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha & 0 \\ \sin \alpha & \cos \alpha & 0 \\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Basically what I did was to rotate the coordinate system with $P$ such that $z$-axis and $(1,2,3)^T$ coincide, then I rotated $xy$-plane by $\alpha$ and then reverted back to original coordinates.

Is this correct ?

Please don't use quaternions or any other voodoo like given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/how-to-find-the-matrix-of-rotation-in-mathbbr3-by-the-angle-a-around-the-v). Please use basic trignometry and linear algebra.

Sorry, normally I don't ask this type of question but I can't verify my results in this case.

Comment: it should be a 1 in the last diagonal place. and the corresponding column in $P$ should be the vector in the direction of the axis of rotation. also $P^{-1}$ should be applied first and $P$ last. but everything else looks fine.

Comment: @mathreadler Sorry I incorrectly formatted my matrix. Can you check again ?

Comment: Generally this is problem for appllication of [Rodrigues formula][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula]. Hard to say whether it is "voodoo"..

Comment: looks better but you need a 1 in the last diagonal spot instead of a 0 or it will become a projection onto the disc of rotation.

Comment: are you sure you have an ON system by the way? I am not so sure about it...

Comment: @Widawensen Although  I think that formula is easy to derive, I don't want to use it.

Comment: @mathreadler What is an ON system ? That $1$ in the last diagonal is a typo

Comment: An ON system is a coordinate system where the basis vectors are pairwise orthogonal to each other. In other words the columns of $P$ should all have scalar product 0 with each other and 1 with themselves.

Comment: @mathreadler It should be an ON system otherwise $P$ won't be invertible right ?

Comment: It can still be invertible as long as the column vectors in $P$ are linearly independent, but the rotation matrix in the middle will not look the same in a non-ON system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find $R$ as $PSP^{-1}$ where $P$ is a rotation (orthonormal transformation) that maps the $x$-axis to the axial vector $(1,2,3)$, and $S$ is a rotation of angle $\alpha$ around the $x$-axis.

Finding $S$ is easy: $$S = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos\alpha&-\sin\alpha\\0&\sin\alpha&\cos\alpha\end{bmatrix}$$

Finding $P$ is more complex. Firstly, $Pe_1={(1,2,3)^T\over\sqrt{1^2+2^2+3^2}}$. Next, we meed to make sure that $Pe_i \perp Pe_j$ for all $i \neq j$, and $|Pe_1|=|Pe_2|=|Pe_3|=1$; for this we can use the cross product: Make $Pe_2={(1,2,3)^T\times e_1 \over |(1,2,3)^T \times e_1|}$, which is the unit vector perpendicular to $e_1$ and $(1,2,3)^T$, and similarly make $Pe_3 = {((1,2,3)^T\times e_1) \times (1,2,3)^T \over |(((1,2,3)^T\times e_1) \times (1,2,3)^T|}$, which is perpendicular to both $Pe_1$ and $Pe_2$ and of unit length. This satisfies all the conditions we need for $P$.

A remark: A key step in finding $P$ is finding a pair of vectors perpendicular to the axial vector and to each other. There is no continuous mapping that does this [because of the hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem#Application_to_computer_graphics). In spite of that, there are [algorithms for doing this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133177/finding-a-unit-vector-perpendicular-to-another-vector/133188) (see Yves Daoust's answer).

Comment: How did you find perpendicular of $(1,2,3)^T$ ?

Comment: @123 $(1,2,3)^T \times (1,0,0)^T = (0,-3,2)^T$

Comment: @123 corrected typo

Comment: Why did you took vector product with $(1,0,0)^T$ not $(0,1,0)^T$ or $(0,0,1)^T$ or something else ?

Comment: @123 Any reason to use something else? See the remark.

Comment: $Pe_2$ just has to be perpendicular to $Pe_1$ right ? So I can use any of infinitely many perpendicular vectors to $Pe_1$ right ?

Comment: @123 yes because a rotation in 3d is a transformation that preserves an axial vector and rotates the plane perpendicular to the axial vector. Since that plane is perpendicular to the axial vector, $Pe_2$ and $Pe_3$  (which form a basis for that plane) must be perpendicular to $Pe_1$ (which is the axial vector). We furthermore make $Pe_2$ perpendicular to $Pe_3$ because it makes rotating the plane easier. We can use any orthonormal basis we want for the plane.